# 403 Forbidden when installing npm - Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04, npm-install

I am trying to install npm and Nodejs on my ubuntu 14.0 server.

I have installed nodejs using `sudo apt-get install nodejs` but when I install `npm` I get 403 Forbidden errors.

```
    $ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.2
libv8-3.14-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy node-async node-block-stream
node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent
node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime
node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs
node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
node-which nodejs-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign node-http-signature
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev libssl-doc libv8-3.14-dev
node-abbrev node-ansi node-archy node-async node-block-stream
node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent
node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini
node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime
node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs
node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
node-which nodejs-dev npm zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
libssl1.0.2 zlib1g
2 upgraded, 53 newly installed, 0 to remove and 257 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,062 kB/5,590 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Then I say `Y`

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libssl1.0.2 libssl-dev libssl-doc
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
```

Then I say `Y` and here is where I get the Forbidden errors.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ trusty/main libssl1.0.2 amd64 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ trusty/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/ trusty/main libssl-doc all 1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                                                                                                            _amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_                                                                                                            amd64.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-doc_1.0.2h-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_                                                                                                            all.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I believe I have trouble installing these packages:

```
libssl1.0.2 libssl-dev libssl-doc
```

Comment: Consult this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034558/apt-get-upgrade-error-403-forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the packages `libssl1.0.2 libssl-dev libssl-doc` are from http, the sources are not safe. That's why ubuntu ignores the download and installation.

Install npm with this command `npm install npm@latest -g` worked for me.

This command will install the latest version on `npm`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```

it should work.

Comment: Thank you but the problem is not that.

Comment: But you don't have key for authenticate that packages. If you tried and it didn't work, can you copy-paste the output?

Comment: After running `sudo apt-get update` command I get  `Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign http://download.webmin.com sarge/contrib Translation-en_US
Ign http://download.webmin.com sarge/contrib Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden`

Comment: I believe I have trouble installing this packages: `libssl1.0.2 libssl-dev libssl-doc`.

Comment: I also get `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: Can you remove that ppa with "sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6" command?

Comment: And also you don't need to install npm after node.js installation. Node.js includes npm for a few years. Just control your npm version with "npm -v". And for the correct installation of node.js visit https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md